# How to present actions to screen conductor from child view?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I am building my first WPF application, a wizard-like app, using Caliburn.Micro. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around a proper design of how to connect the screens. I have a `Conductor<Screen>` as my shell view model, and then I do `ActivateItem` on my first screen. So far, all is well. From here though, how should screens best tell the conductor what actions are possible on this screen (eg Next, Previous, Cancel, etc), and what to do for a given action?

All the examples I've seen have been fairly simple and did not include such concerns. I could of course let each screen define it's own buttons, and then have the conductor subscribe an event handler to each of them, but it will get very messy (there are around 10 screens, with between one and three buttons on each).

I experimented with letting the screens expose an `AvailableActions` property which the shell could bind to and display the correct buttons, but I couldn't figure out a way to connect the buttons to the corresponding screen without adding a lot of mess.

As far as I understand the design philosophy, I should avoid letting the screen's view models having any knowledge about each other, instead the conductor should be the one controlling the flow. Yet, I don't want the conductor to have to have special case code in the conductor for each screen on which buttons are available. Am I correct in this? How should I in that case meet both goals?

Answer (score 0):

It is customary to use the [`Page` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx) to implement *wizard-like* applications:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="SDKSample.HomePage">
  Hello, from the XBAP HomePage!
</Page>
```

You can add `Hyperlink` elements to navigate between the pages:

```
<Hyperlink NavigateUri="UriOfPageToNavigateTo.xaml">
  Navigate to Another Page
</Hyperlink>
```

Please read the [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for further information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it is a company constraint that all our WPF apps use Caliburn. I think my main problem is in the design, though, so let's discuss around your sample. Is it considered a good design to let the view model of the page know what the next/previous page is? What if there are branches, so I need to apply some logic to decide the next page?

Comment: Each `Page` should have its own view model and these view models should *not* know anything about each other. However, it is customary to have a parent view model which *knows about* the child view models.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I felt would be reasonable as well. However, this doesn't really mesh with your example, where your `Hyperlink` element has a reference to the next page (so not in the view model but in the view, but I would think the reasoning is the same there?). How would the `NavigateUri` property be set then?

Comment: If you had followed my provided links, then you would have seen that the code came from the linked page. Furthermore, if you had looked at the [`HyperlinkButton.NavigateUri` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton.navigateuri(v=vs.95).aspx) page on MSDN, then you would have seen that it is bindable and therefore each `Page` does *not* need to know about each other. Please read the linked pages for further information.